# Black screen appears when trying to enter ubuntu - dual boot (windows10 - ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, mysql, rsync

I am having problem with Ubuntu again. Everything was perfect (for 1 month), after I installed `mysql 5.7.12` and `gtk 3.0` the problem started. When I try to enter Ubuntu a blank screen shows up. However, I do not think, the problem is related with `mysql` nor `gtk`.

When I try to kill process these lines are appearing.

```
wait-for-state stop/waiting
*Stopping rsync daamond rsync 
*speech-dispatcher disabled: /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
*MySQL Community Server 5.7.12 is already stopped
nm.dispatcher.action: Caught signal 15, shutting down...
Asking all remaining processes to terminate...
```

Shortly, I can not enter Ubuntu but I can enter Windows 10.
What is the problem? What should I do? Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Most blank screen on boot issues for me historically have been due to an issue with the nvidia driver or another proprietary driver.  Some programs can interact in odd ways that cause the error i.e. wine.  If you have nvidia-current installed you may try removing it to isolate the error.

Can you get to the Ubuntu login screen or does it go blank before?

Comment: Unfortunately, ı can not get login screen. However when ı try to enter terminal with ctrl+alt+fn-f2 , ı can write commands but the interesting part is when ı dont write anything around 5-6 second, the screen again turn back to black and seems like it is frozen... cannot do anything.

Comment: On the other hand, ı had some problem on installation process around 1.5 month ago. The problems are generally about nvidia (as you mentioned), but the thing is, when ı tried to install nvdia-current-stable version, the system was not responding good . I was facing with this kind a problem. http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error . But ı solved the problem in some way, ı cant remember which. "By the way, screen goes blank before"- as answer your question above.

Comment: Are you using lightdm as the display manager?  I believe this one play best with Nvidia.  If not try

$ dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

Comment: I am using lightdm, ı tried your advice but nothing happened. However, the good news is ı reached some points. As ı told you earlier, ı can reach to terminal via  ctrl+alt+fn-f2, then the screen goes black if ı dont do anything for 5-6 seconds. I realized that the system is not frozen, when ı write ctrl+alt+fn-f2, ıt goes to terminal again and the process continues where it lefts of.

Comment: It is a kind a process which similar to "sleep mode" but instead of desktop display on screen, there is a black screen. Really interesting...

Comment: You may find something useful in your  Xorg log file.  You can use a command like 'cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep error'